# Can't retrieve data from firebase

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase

I'm trying to retrieve data from firebase and its in the format of this:

```
>Users
--->UID
------>email:
------>height:
------>etc...
```

For some reason the UID keeps returning undefined when I try to get the value of say email.  This is the code that attempts to retrieve the data:

```
.factory('Chats', function($rootScope) {
  // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array
  var chats;

  return {
    all: function() {
      return chats;
    },
    initialize: function(isLoggedIn) {

      var data = $rootScope.ref.getAuth().uid;
      console.log("initialize: " + data);
      if(isLoggedIn == true) {
        $rootScope.ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
          console.log("Value: " + snapshot.val());
          console.log("Users: " + snapshot.val().users);
          console.log("Data: " + snapshot.val().users.data.email);
        }, function (errorObject) {
          console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
        });
      }
}
};
})
```

It breaks when it gets the the third console.log(the 'Data' one), it throws an exception saying:

```
Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
```

But when I log the variable data1 right before the if statement it returns the correct UID of the user in the form of a string so I don't understand why its telling me its undefined.  All i'm trying to do is dig down my firebase tree and retrieve the values of the users(email, height, etc) based on the UID of the user - which I retrieve by calling ref.getAuth().uid.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading the root of your Firebase and then try to access:

```
snapshot.val().users.data.email
```

Which corresponds to:

```
/users/data/email
```

If you check your JSON data, you'll see that `/users` has no child node called `data`. To use the *value* of data, you need to use bracket notation:

```
snapshot.val().users[data].email
```

Note that you're loading way more data than you should with your approach. Your users will probably appreciate it if you only download their data from the database, which you can do with:

```
$rootScope.ref.child("users").child(data).on("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log("Data: " + snapshot.val().email);
}, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

Final point: if you bind the email address to `$scope`, you'll find that the Angular views don't immediately pick it up. This is because the code in your `on()` callback is called asynchronously and by that time AngularJS is not aware of your actions anymore. You can find out how to make AngularJS aware of the changes in this answer: [Firebase callbacks and AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065367/firebase-callbacks-and-angularjs). But alternativelyL consider using [AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/) to avoid this problem altogether.

Comment: Hey Frank, thanks for your answer - it worked!  Quick question though is there a way in Angular to wait for Firebase to retrive the data before moving on to the next line of code?  The code is in my service.js and returns the object with the users information - my controller calls the service.  My controller then sets the return value of the service to a variable but it seems like the controller doesn't wait for the service to return therefore it sets the variable to undefined.

Comment: There (thankfully) is no way to make code wait for data that is asynchronously loaded in a browser. Read the last two links in my answer for ways to address this.

Comment: Look into async functions, using the async/await syntax. It is at stage 3 of the ECMAScript standardization process. It allows you to write code as if it is synchronous while staying asynchronous, so @MatTaNg, you could call to Firebase, and your code would "wait" before executing the next line, though under the hood it actually isn't blocking anything.