# How to update $rootScope in Angular 1 inside an async callback?

Tags: html, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm sure this is a very common issue but for some reason I can't find a solution that works.

I have a very simple setup with Firebase Realtime Database and Angular 1. I have this directive in my html

```
<div id="usersListWrapper" ng-controller="UsersListController" ng-init="loadUsersList()">
```

Then inside my `loadUsersList()` method, I make a call to Firebase Database to fetch the data

```
$rootScope.users = [];

var usersRef = firebase.database().ref('/users');
usersRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log("loaded users list");
    var users = snapshot.val();
    updateUsersTable(users);
});
```

Then finally, inside `updateUsersTable(users)`, I update my `$rootScope.users` variable

```
var updateUsersTable = function(users) {
    $.each(users, function(key, value) {
        var user = {
            username: key,
            ...
        }

        $rootScope.users.push(user);
    }
}
```

However, even though the `$rootScope.users` variable updates correctly (I verified using the devtools inside Chrome), the html doesn't update :/

Apologies in advance if this is a duplicate question. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you need to run a digest cycle.  $scope.$apply(function() { $rootScope.users.push(user);});

Comment: @LT56 From what I read, it is bad to manually call `$apply`. However, I have tried that as well and it was causing issues whenever I ADDED something to the list. I kept getting this: `Error: $apply already in progress`

Comment: I would put the scope.$apply on the event listener b/c AngularJS doesn't know when the event is fired since it's not managing it. ie: usersRef.on('value', scope.$apply(function () { <your code here> });

Answer (score 0):

$rootScope is not an appropriate place for you to be storing your user objects. Generally speaking, modifying $rootScope should be considered something you do when there are no other options.

What you should be doing is creating a userService and injecting it whereever you need access to user data.

The same advice is generally true for using ng-init as well. I'm guessing you're just getting started with Angularjs. I'd highly recommend you familiarize yourself with John Papa's Angularjs style guide: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md. It's a bit dated in that it doesn't cover components, which are EVERYTHING, but following the style guide makes migration to components super easy.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here seems to work: [Firebase callbacks and AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065367/firebase-callbacks-and-angularjs)

Kinda hacky but it works I guess. Thank you for those who answered.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment above I would put the **scope.$apply** on the event listener b/c **AngularJS** doesn't know when the event is fired since it's not managing it. ie:

```
 usersRef.on('value', scope.$apply(function () { 
    console.log("loaded users list");
    var users = snapshot.val();
    updateUsersTable(users);
 }));
```

Or you could look into **$evalAsync**. From the AngularJS docs:

> $**evalAsync**([expression], [locals]); Executes the expression on the
>   current scope at a later point in time.
>
> The $evalAsync makes no guarantees as to when the expression will be
>   executed, only that:
>
> it will execute after the function that scheduled the evaluation
>   (preferably before DOM rendering). at least one $digest cycle will be
>   performed after expression execution.