# After load the page function is called but not show array data in HTMLview in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have create a shopping website AngularJs in which we have to get the product list from the Firebase db.

```js
//Used for iterate the key and value
function objToArray(batchesObj) {
     var arr = [];
     for (var prop in batchesObj) {
        if(!batchesObj[prop].isDeleted) {
           //Adding key in object
           batchesObj[prop].key = prop;
           arr.push(batchesObj[prop]);
          }
         }
     return arr;
 }



$scope.productDto  =[];

$scope.getProductData = function() {
 //USED FOR CREAT THE FIREABSE REF ANS GET LIMITED DATA...
var ref= firebase.database().ref("sellerProduct").on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var value = snapshot.val();
    $scope.productDto = objToArray(value);
});
}
$scope.getProductData();
```

```html
<div class="productInfo  w3-col m3  w3-card-4 w3-margin-left" 
    ng-repeat ="list in productArray  | orderBy: getUpdateDate : true">
</div>
```

Product list is properly get, but not display initially in the view section. I don't understand what mistake I made. How to fix this problem?

Comment: The `on('value'` callback fires asynchronously, which means that Angular is not expecting any updates and doesn't know to update the views. For a solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065367/firebase-callbacks-and-angularjs/13083437#13083437

Comment: thank you sir..it works for me